# Why does Functor not expose a default implementation of fmap?

Tags: haskell, functor

In the `Functor` class type definition:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Why does `fmap` not have a default implementation? Something like that:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    fmap fn (f a) = (f $ (fn) a)
```

When I write instances of `Functor`, I write the *same* code for each instance manually. Is there a way for me to specify a default implementation?

Comment: @Bush What's the type of `f`?  Is it supposed to be a constructor?  In the type signature it's a type variable constrained to be an instance of `Functor`, but in the pattern match it has to be a constructor.  Functions don't have constructors in Haskell, so you can't pattern match on them.

Comment: @bheklilr, I am  thinking `f` is a *type constructor with a single parameter*. I study a subject and still not up to the end understood it.

Comment: @Bush Unfortunately, it's not possible to match generically on type constructors (without using Data.Generic or something).  Besides, most interesting types are not made up of a single constructor with a single parameter, this wouldn't work for tuples, Either, Maybe, or lists.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data T1 a = T1 a
  deriving Functor
data T2 a = T2 a
  deriving Functor
```

As to why there's no default implementation for functor: your proposal only works if `f` is the identity functor (up to isomorphism). That is, it works on

```
data F a = F a
```

but it is not going to work on

```
data F a = F a a
```

or

```
data F a = F (Int -> a) [a] (Maybe a)
```

which require more complex `fmap`s.

While one can not write a default `fmap` which works in every case, in many simple cases such as the above ones it seems trivial to spot what `fmap` should be.
Fortunately, we now have `derive Functor` which covers these simple cases.

Comment: It is unpossible - deriving of Functor: `Can't make a derived instance of 'Functor T1'`

Comment: @Bush Works here. Post all your code, and be sure you used the `LANGUAGE` pragma.

Comment: I found my mistake: I **added** your code into the "tail" of my hs-file. But if I  put your code in the "head" of my hs file - it works fine.

Comment: @Bush, `LANGUAGE` and `OPTIONS_GHC` pragmas always have to go at the top of the file, above the `module` line.

Comment: Why would it not be possible to automatically unpack `data F a = F a a`? DeriveFunctor seems to have no problems with `F Int`. See https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-prime/2007-March/002137.html

Comment: @Maarten `deriving Functor` does work in that case. But it has to be a GHC extension which produces the right instance, you can't simply have a default general functor implementation as the OP asked.

Comment: Not all I concede, but I wonder about your example. I can't imagine a case of `data F a .. = F a a ..` where the implementation of fmap is not trivial.

Comment: @Maarten Indeed it is trivial. But the OP was asking for a single implementation working for each functor, which is impossible: `data F a = F a` and `data G a = G a a` can not have the same code.